# How to mix angular2 components into an existing requirejs backbone project?

Tags: backbone.js, angular, requirejs

I wonder if anyone has ever loaded angular2 components into an existing requirejs backbone project, as a way to slowly migrate a backbone require.js project into Angular2 ?

regards

Sean

Comment: Although I haven't tried it but What you can do is load angular using require and bootstrap your ng-app manually whenever you need to.